Stalk of composition of morphisms of sheaves and composition of stalks of morphisms of sheaves
Given a topological space $X$. Let $f:F\to G$  be a morphism of sheaves of abelian groups. Naturally, $f$ induces a morphism of stalks  $f_x: F_x\to G_x$ for any $x\in X$. Additionally, there exists    another morphism $g:G\to H$  of sheaves of abelian groups.
Question: Does  $(g\circ f)_x  = g_x\circ f_x$ holds?
(For presheaves, one can refer Stalks of Composition of Morphisms of Presheaves   I think we can apply the same method in our setting.  But I'm not confident.)

Yes, this is correct. That post that you reference can actually be applied directly since a sheaf is a presheaf.
You may have been worried since some definitions differ when thinking of a sheaf as a presheaf (such as the definition of a surjective morphism) but the definition of the stalk is not one of these.
